# what is the need of xsl when compared with css?

Tags: css, xslt

Well i happened to run through some code snippets and couldnt understand the need for xsl when the same thing can be done using css.
For example

```
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/css" href = "6a.css" ?>
<ENG-COLLEGE>
   <XYZ>
     <USN>145456</USN>
     <NAME>ABC</NAME>
     <COLLEGE>TYUIT</COLLEGE>
     <BRANCH>ISE</BRANCH>
     <YEAR>2003</YEAR>
     <EMAIL>abc@gmail.com</EMAIL>
   </XYZ>
<ENG-COLLEGE>
```

Equivalent CSS code for styling that

```
USN{font-family:'sans serif';color:orange;font-size:15pt;}
NAME{font-family:'arial';color:red;font-size:15pt;}
COLLEGE{font-family:'Times New Roman';color:lime;font-size:15pt;}
BRANCH{font-family:'Comic Sans MS';color:gray;font-size:15pt;}
YEAR{font-family:'Century Gothic';color:blue;font-size:15pt;}
EMAIL{font-family:'Georgia';color:green;font-size:15pt;}
```

Althought the same styling could be achieved using xsl , which involves more lines of code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0"
         xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns = "">

 <xsl:template match = "ENG-COLLEGE">

   <html><head><title>Test XSL</title>
    </head><body bgcolor="lightgreen">
   <center><h2>INFORMATION </h2>
    <table border="1">

<tr><td>USN</td><td>NAME</td><td>COLLEGE</td><td>BRANCH</td><td>YEAR</td>    <td>EMAIL</td></tr>

     <xsl:for-each select ="VTU">
     <tr>
       <td> <xsl:value-of select = "USN" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select = "NAME" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select = "COLLEGE" /></td>
    <td> <xsl:value-of select = "BRANCH" /></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select = "YEAR" /></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select = "EMAIL" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>

     </table>

      </center>
      </body></html>

     </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

well am i missing something here , i mean why would anyone style using  xsl when css can make the job so easy.

Comment: Umm... I don't think this is a proper question. It's obvious that OP knows what is CSS and XSLT from posted examples. So this is kind of subjective "versus" questions.

Comment: I think it's a genuine enough question: the OP does not really understand what XSLT is for if he thinks that CSS can do everything that XSLT can.

Comment: @LarsH: I don't agree. If OP intentions are to understand some use case he/she didn't realize, then the question wouldn't be stated as as a "versus" questions. As a proof about how this doesn't help others, please run a search about `[xslt]` tag and you will find some of this questions at the top of list obfuscating the results.

Answer (score 6):

CSS applies style and positioning. XSLT transforms one XML document into another. They're not doing the same job at all.

Comment: well when i open myfile.xml in the browser i get the same view. In which circumstances should i go for css and which one for xsl ?

Comment: You use CSS when you want to apply style and positioning, and you use XSL when you want to transform one XML document into another.

Comment: @Rahul: CSS is not parseable by a XML parser. XSL is.

Comment: i would be glad if you could quote an example where strictly xsl is used and css cannot.

Comment: Where a producer produces an XML document, but the consumer that's next in the chain needs a different format.

Comment: Rahul, you can look at your example.  In the first example, you're using a browser that is applying CSS to an XML document directly.  In the second example, you're using XSL transform that XML document into an HTML document.

Comment: In my own development, I often use XSL to transform meta-data information about my database into code.  I pull a ResultSet from the database and turn it into XML.  Then, I execute XSL on it to turn it into code.

Answer (score 1):

> Well i happened to run through some
>   code snippets and couldnt understand
>   the need for xsl when the same thing
>   can be done using css. For example

What's true for that CSS-oriented example is not true in general.
If your input XML contained many `<XYZ>` elements:

```
<ENG-COLLEGE>
   <XYZ>
     <USN>145456</USN>
     <NAME>ABC</NAME>
     <COLLEGE>TYUIT</COLLEGE>
     <BRANCH>ISE</BRANCH>
     <YEAR>2003</YEAR>
     <EMAIL>abc@gmail.com</EMAIL>
   </XYZ>
   <XYZ>
     <USN>145456</USN>
     <NAME>DEF</NAME>
     ...
   </XYZ>
   etc.
</ENG-COLLEGE>
```

and you need to produce a table of these records, sorted by the content of the `NAME` element, omitting those whose `YEAR` is prior to 2000, with the `EMAIL` address surrounded by a "mailto" link... How would you do that in CSS?

Comment: Yes, but do note that besides the sorting (not sure about "mailto:" link because it's posible with propietary CSS) the other stuff can be done with CSS.

Comment: @Alej: I didn't realize CSS could filter on values of text nodes.

Comment: @Alejandro , what exactly you mean by proprietary CSS ? i thought its an open source language right ?

Comment: @Rahul, do you mean an open standard? (CSS per se does not have "source") Yes CSS is an open standard, but companies often take public standards and add their own proprietary extensions to them.